# A simple java program output is not as expected with IO

Tags: java

i've  a code which is not working as expected, it has to do something with System.in.read() method. the program is meant to read from the console until i press 'c' or 'C'

```
import java.io.*;

public class Input{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
        char b;

        outer:
        do{
            b= (char)System.in.read();
            System.out.println(b);
            if(b=='c'||b=='C'){
               break outer;
            }
        } while(true);      
    }
}
```

output is

```
D:\ex\1>java Input
d
d



c
c

D:\ex\1>
```

why are there empty lines in the output

Comment: because you pressed enter at the end of a line??

Comment: you also print line feed and carriage return. these arent visible on console

Comment: yes after inputting the value i pressed return key. but how to change the code so there will be no blank line

Answer (score 2):

When you call `read` the first time, it reads `'d'` and prints it with a new line (because you used `println` instead of `print`). This explains the first new line. After the loop's first iteration, `read` is called again. This time, it reads the carriage return character `'\r'`. The third time `read` is called, it reads the new line character `'\n'`. That's why there are 3 new lines.

> Where do those new line characters come from?

Each time you enter a character, you press "enter" right? That's the new line! Since you're using Windows, it inserts `\r\n`. While on my Mac, a new line is just `\n`. That's why your code produces 2 instead of 3 new lines when run on my Mac.

The solution to this is not to read the new lines:

```
do{
     b= (char)System.in.read();
     if (b == '\r' || b == '\n') continue;
     System.out.println(b);
        if(b=='c'||b=='C'){break outer;}

}while(true);
```

Or you can use a `Scanner`:

```
char b;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
outer:
do{
    b= sc.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
    System.out.println(b);
    if(b=='c'||b=='C'){break outer;}

}while(true);
```

Comment: I would really suggest using a Scanner or another Character based solution. Interpreting byte streams always means you need to handle character encoding. Because it is a pain in the ass, you really want to someone else taking care of it. Using a Scanner you can pass in the _charsetName_ you want the Input to be treated as.

Answer (score 0):

simply replace `System.out.println(b);` with

```
int a = (int) b;
if (a != 13 && a != 10) {
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

it will not print the char, if the int value of it is line feed and carriage return